# Process async results in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-ce

I have a WinCE C# app that polls a (JAVA) server for messages coming in asynchronously. What I want to achieve is that I want to poll the server, and when a result is returned, queue it up and then process that result in another thread. I want to isolate the async receive thread from the process thread, because after processing the response, i might have to make additional POSTs to the server.

What i have for now is a class similar to the one shown here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

for making async requests to the server and reading the response. I have modified the class to include a custom timeout but that shouldn't matter.

What happens in my app is that I start polling in a thread 'pollingThread', and get the response from the server. Incase of a timeout, the response will be null, otherwise I try to process the response.

I want to send the response string to another thread who can work on processing it, while my pollingThread goes back to continue polling the server. I can't figure out how to get the response onto another thread. I know how to do it using Monitor.Pulse on big windows, but unfortunately its not available on NETCF 3.5.

Any insights?

Thanks

EDIT: @Damon8or

I tried using AutoReset but for some reason, the WaitOne() doesn't realize that the other thread has already Set() the event and so it misses the data coming through. Here's what i have:

The AutoresetEvent `_process` is declared static and is visible to both methods

```
ThreadStart processMethod= new ThreadStart(process);
processingThread= new Thread(processJSONMethod);
processingThread.IsBackground = true;
processingThread.Start();

ThreadStart startMethod = new ThreadStart(Poll);
connectionThread = new Thread(startMethod);
connectionThread.IsBackground = true;                    
connectionThread.Start();
```

inside of the Poll, I have `_process.Set()` after receive a string from the server. In the process method, I have:

```
while (_keepPolling)
{

_process.WaitOne();

string text= MyQueue.Dequeue();
Debug.WriteLine("Returned: " + text

}
```

And I don't see the debug line being printed. The poll method produceses and queues the string and goes back to polling.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to make sure that I keep polling in my pollingThread while the result is being processed in another thread. I can't figure out how to wake up a thread that does the processing of the result after a result is pushed to the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either AutoResetEvent or ManualResetEvent to signal your worker thread.  Here's a simple example how.

```
    using System; 
    using System.Linq; 
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Text; 
    using System.Threading; 

    namespace QueueDoodles 
    {
    class Program
    {
        public static readonly string[] data = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var running = true;
            var rand = new Random();
            var q = new Queue<string>();
            var qEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var pollThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                while (running)
                {
                    // Queue the next value
                    var value = data[rand.Next(data.Length)];
                    q.Enqueue(value);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} queued {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, value);

                    // Signal waiting thread
                    qEvent.Set();

                    // Simulate polling
                    Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(100));
                }
            }));
            pollThread.Name = "Poll Thread";

            var workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                while (running)
                {
                    // Wait on the queue
                    if (!qEvent.WaitOne())
                        break;
                    qEvent.Reset();

                    // Process the next queue item
                    var value = q.Dequeue();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} queued {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, value);
                }
            }));
            workerThread.Name = "Worker Thread";

            // Start the poll thread
            pollThread.Start();

            // Give it some time to fill queue
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Start the worker thread
            workerThread.Start();

            // Wait for keyboard input
            Console.ReadLine();
            running = false;
            qEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at the edit on the question, I couldn't fit it all in a comment. Thanks

Comment: I added a Thread.Sleep(10); right after the set and it seemed to have helped the WaitOne() to get out of the wait. Not sure what to make of that, but now I have another issue where the two threads aren't operating parallel. The processing thread seems to block the connectionThread, even though it shouldn't. 

Just as a sanity check, I have both the threads as background threads. Does that make a difference? Thanks

Comment: I tried switching to AutoResetEvent in my QueueDoodle code and it worked as well - commented out the Reset() call since that's done automatically with that type.  There's got to be something going on with the event or your processing thread.  I've used these event classes extensively and they always work.  Some things to experiment with...

-Add debug statments in your processing thread to see if it even running.
-Add a timeout to the WaitOne(1000), and check the return just to see if the event is triggering.
-Try ManualResetEvent to see if it behaves differently.

Comment: Background shouldn't matter.  If the thread.sleep(10) helped, it's probably from the poll thread spinning, or another thread that hogging CPU. You shouldn't need the sleep unless you want to specifically force another thread to run at some point.  I removed the sleep call in my sample and it still ran fine.  I know that's not that helpful, but perhaps take some things out of the equation, and just concentrate getting the thread signaling going, then start adding processing and actually polling back into the mix.

Comment: Yep, the Thread.Sleep(10) after the Set() in Autoreset solved my issue. I believe the Set was happening at a point where there was no one waiting, and then when I did go to wait right after the set, there was nothing for me to fetch. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool.  I'm still skeptical the sleep is necessary.  And shouldn't matter about the waitone occuring before or after the set.  Just a tip in the future you may want to release one or multiple threads when signaling the event, P/Invoke EventModify to pulse the event.  On manual events all waiting threads are release, on auto one one.

Answer (score 1):

The queue class is thread safe, why not use a queue to queue your data?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx

Comment: Also, queuing the data is not my problem. I can use queues for it. My problem is how to wake up my 'processor' thread to process the result while making sure that my polingThread continues to poll